# Restricting access to all domains but one on the system/proxy level

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, proxy, iptables, squid

I'm trying to restrict access [on https level] to only one domain (from docker container). I found a way to do it with squid proxy https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-add-dns-filtering-to-your-nat-instance-with-squid/ but seems like it requires Man In the Middle setup for the ssl connections. If possible I would like to avoid it. Is there any simple and secure way to restrict outbound traffic from a linux container? - my use case is around creating a secure environment for a containerized nodejs application so even if any mallicious library tries to access external urls - it's automatically blocked.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to setup Squid for MITM then you need some *dirty* workaround, like:

- Blocking resulting IP with iptables (IE periodically querying for updated IP addresses to block)
- Faking DNS resolution (IE resolving specific domains to localhost)